# Cambiar el mes de una fecha de Español a Inglés

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo tengo esta fecha:
`10-Ago-2021 20:50`

Como cambiar el mes `Ago` a `Aug`, y así con el resto de meses que difieren del Español al Inglés como Enero, Abril, Agosto y Diciembre.

Simplemente se puede utilizar un `.replace(mesES, mesEN)`, pero quiero saber si hay otra manera más simple de realizarlo.

Comment: Javascript limpio, sin ningún framework?

Comment: @Alfabravo si un framework lo realiza de mejor forma, si claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo realicé con la función `replace()`

```js
const fechaES = '10-Ago-2021 18:00';

const monthEN = {
    Ene: 'Jan', Abr: 'Apr', Ago: 'Aug', Dic: 'Dec'
}

const fechaEN = fechaES.replace(/Ene|Abr|Ago|Dic/gi, function (matched) {
    return monthEN[matched];
});

console.log(fechaEN);
```

Comment: La fecha en español abreviada debe llevar punto 'Ago.'Te recomiendo no inventar la rueda y usar alguna librería que te resuelva las traducciones. Una muy conocida es https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Desde una api obtengo la fecha y viene en ese formato: "10-Ago-2021 18:00", utilicé moment pero no detecta las fechas con el mes en español @FrancoBerardi

Comment: @FrancoBerardi, el punto al final del mes en una fecha en español depende de la variante de español. Por ejemplo en el sistema `locale` para España (`es-ES`) no lleva punto, pero para Venezuela (`es-VE`), sí que lo lleva, puedes ver un ejemplo en este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/virtual_kur2/bahgk6qf/4/). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras es un buen punto. Intenté buscar algún justificativo/documento en el método toLocale del objeto date, pero no encontré nada. En la CLDR, todos los ejemplos que tienen en español son con el punto al final. Te comparto el link: https://www.unicode.org/cldr/cldr-aux/charts/30/verify/dates/es.html

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una forma de hacerlo usando `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```js
let d = new Date('08-10-2021 14:00:00');
let ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);
let mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(d);
let da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: 'numeric' }).format(d);
let ho =  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { timeStyle: 'medium' }).format(d);
console.log(`${da}-${mo}-${ye} ${ho}`);
```

Comment: La fecha viene con el mes en español, por ej: '08-Ago-2021 14:00'. Al realizar el new Date() da como resultado "Invalid Date"